# Generating customized vector OSM map files from OpenStreetMap and other data?

Tags: openstreetmap, data, vector, export, mapping

I am looking for a way (e.g. tutorial?) to generate my own customized (offline) maps in OSM format. By *"customized"* I mean adding data (not just define a region of interest) to an existing OSM map (e.g. OpenTopoMap), then export the augmented map into a new `.osm`-file.

What I managed to do:

- load OSM maps (e.g. OpenTopoMap) in QGIS, download the canvas into an `.osm`-file and convert it to a sqlite db, and import points, polygons, polylines
- load other data into QGIS (e.g. manually generated (vector) points)
- export the canvas to tiles using QTiles either to a directory or to a `.mbtiles`-file. However, this is the critical point: this export is way too large and the resolution of the tiles is bad, so I am looking to export the canvas in the vectorized form

How can I augment maps in OSM format with own data and store it as a new (vector) `.osm`-file?

Preferably in QGIS, other programs are fine as long as they are free and run in Linux. The full style e.g. the shading in OpenTopoMap and the elevation curves should be preserved.

Comment: Is this for commercial use? Or is it for home/studies/non-profit? Because I can provide a free solution but only if it's not for commercial use.

Comment: This is strictly for private/home/non-profit use.

Comment: I guess this post/question is related to mine: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85863/how-to-capture-contour-lines-from-osm-cycle-map-as-vector?rq=1
I hope there is an easier way to preserve contours and hill shading in the meantime.

Comment: Many questions here as the whole approach doesn't make a lot of sense to me: what is opentopo? (opentopomap.org?) What kind of data do you want to add? Just a few POIs, new ways? Why can't you add an overlay layer? Taking rendered tiles (=images) and trying to add something to them or even regenerate raw data seems like a very bad idea. I for sure would add the data to the RAW xml data and then render my own opentopo map. That means you have to set up a rendering stack using mapnik!

Comment: I educated myself a bit more (still very new to mapping!). I seek to generate the own OSM maps with contours, hill shading, and additional personal vector data. In that sense: use OpenCycleMaps/opentopo.org, add some own vector stuff, export it again to OSM. So yes, I am creating an overlay (vector) layer, add my vector stuff but whenever I export it (osm download in qgis) all the hillshading/contours gets lost. This seems to be obvious as the rendering requires a style sheet. But I think it should be possible to store e.g. OpenCycleMaps/opentopo.org with augmented vector data for offline use.

Comment: As a note: I read that e.g. OpenCycleMaps uses the contours from an SRTM download (and hill shading from geotif by USGS?). If you want to augment contour/hillshading maps with your own data and store them offline efficiently (i.e. my question above) I hope this does not mean that you basically have to reproduce the workpipeline of OpenCycleMap but can directly use their data, augment it and store it locally.

Comment: OpenCycleMap did not publish their stylesheets, the only thing you can do with it is to view their tiles (again, that's PNG format image files, not vector data!) in your browser, adhering to their terms of service. Mass download for offline use is discouraged and will get you blocked.

Comment: ok. I am not bound to OpenCycleMaps. Anything that has hillshading, contours and city/town names/structures is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Given your response to my comment, you could try FME.

***NB:*** I work for the people who make FME

It's [free](https://www.safe.com/fme/fme-desktop/home-use-license/) for non-commercial use. Anyway, here's what it would look like if I added extra emergency data to an OSM layer:

[image]

After installing (yes there is a Linux version)...

1. Start Workbench. Press Ctrl+G to set up an OSM to OSM translation
2. In the translation, press Ctrl+Alt+R to add a reader to read the additional data
3. Just map the additional data into the OSM output layers

There's probably more work to it than that, depending on how you want to map the data/attributes, and what OSM layers allow which geometries. I know a little about OSM data structures but am not expert. Still I can get data into an OSM file in some form fairly easily. I think it's a good starting point, and there are other supported formats that may be of use too.